# Probabilistic interpretation for representation of unity using the zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, riemann-zeta

There's a cute identity, I believe due to [Borwein, Bradley and Crandall](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/borwein1.pdf) (Section 4):

$$1=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\zeta(n)-1).$$

There are some generalizations in the linked paper as well.

Question: Is there an interesting probabilistic interpretation of this that comes up somewhere? In other words, a random variable $X$ such that $P(X=n)=\zeta(n)-1$, for $n\geq 2$.

Note that $\zeta(n)>1$ for all $n>1$, and $0<\zeta(n)-1<1$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Comment: That is curious and amusing.  That would be pretty cool if it comes up naturally as a probability distribution.

Comment: Such random variable definitely _exists_; its probability (mass) function is defined by your requirement $P(X=n)=\zeta(n)-1$, for $n\geq 2$. I think your question is rather _what is the physical meaning of such random variable_, or _what real-life experiment gives rise to such random variable_

Comment: @LuisMendo: Yes that's what I mean by "interpretation somewhere," however I would prefer an example where the distribution can be derived.

Answer (score 5):

There is a family of distributions called Zipf (sometimes zeta) distributions. A random variable $X$ with this distribution satisfies
$$\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac{n^{-s}}{\zeta(s)},\qquad\qquad n=1,2,3,\dots$$
where $s>1$ is a parameter of the distribution. A main interesting property of this is that the prime factors of $X$ are independent, that is the events $[p_1|x],[p_2|X],\dots,[p_k|X]$ are independent for primes $p_1,\dots,p_k.$

I don't know about the case your talking about although it seems to be a special case of the distribution discussed in the paper *A Probability Distribution Associated with the Hurwitz Zeta Function* from *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society*, vol. 99 no. 4 (Apr. 1987), p. 757-759. You may be able to access it on [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2046488).

**EDIT:** [Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-099-04/S0002-9939-1987-0877052-1/S0002-9939-1987-0877052-1.pdf) it is from the AMS.

Comment: I don't suppose there's an application of these somewhere?

Comment: Not one I know of. The linked paper claims some kind of connection to Poisson distributions.